# Relationship of optimal solutions between the total function and the sub function

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming, global-optimization

This is an unconstrained convex optimization problem. Let $\mathcal{N}=\left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$, $2\leq n<\infty$. Suppose there are many strongly convex functions $f_i(x)$, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $i\in\mathcal{N}$. The total function is defined as
\begin{align}
f(r)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(r),~~r\in\mathbb{R}^2.
\end{align}
We know that the local functions $f_i(x)$ and total function $f(r)$ have their own unique optimal solutions defined as $x_i^*$ and $r^*$, respectively.

Intuitively, I think these optimal solutions should satisfy the following relationship

**1. if $x_i^*$ are all bounded, then $r^*$ is bounded,**

**2. or even $r^*$ should be in the convex hull of $x_i^*$.**

But I don't know how to prove it. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4747980/relationship-of-optimal-solutions-between-the-total-function-and-the-sub-functio

Comment: I've revised the description, $n$ is a postive constant greater than 2.